# Expressão Regular R

Tags: r, regex

Tenho uma variável que indica o ano do Ensino Fundamental que um aluno está cursando, mas essa variável não foi preenchida de forma única.

Por exemplo  o 1º Ano do Ensino Fundamental por estar indicado como `1º ano`, `1º Ano`, `1º ANO`, `1 º ano`. Alguém sabe indicar como posso incluir todas as possíveis formas dentro de um `grep` por exemplo. Eu sei que posso fazer alguns `grep`, só que pra isso eu precisaria saber ao certo cada forma que foi preenchido e seria mais útil algo automático.

Segue um `dput` de parte das informações.

```
c("1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"2º ano", "2º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "4º ano", 
"4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", 
"1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"2º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", 
"4º ano", "4º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "1º ano", 
"1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", 
"4º ano", "5 º ano", "5 º ano", "5 º ano", "5 º ano", "1º ano", 
"1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"2º ano", "2º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", 
"4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", 
"5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "1º ANO", "1º ANO", "1º ANO", 
"1º ANO", "1º ANO", "1º ANO", "2º ANO", "2º ANO", "2º ANO", "2º ANO", 
"2º ANO", "2º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", 
"3º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", 
"5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "1 º ano", 
"1 º ano", "1 º ano", "1 º ano", "1 º ano", "1 º ano", "2ºano", 
"2ºano", "2ºano", "2ºano", "2ºano", "2ºano", "3ºano", "3ºano", 
"3ºano", "3ºano", "3ºano", "3ºano", "4ºano", "4ºano", "4ºano", 
"4ºano", "4ºano", "4ºano", "5ºano")
```

Comment: Se não me engano o `grep` possuí um parâmetro `ignore case`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complementando o exemplo do Henrique:

Seleciona todos os campos que possui o "1".

```
txt[grep("1", txt)]
```

Seleciona todos os campos que possui o "1" ou textualmente "Primeiro".

```
txt[grep("1|primeiro", txt, ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

Comment: eu pensei nesse caso agora, estava fazendo os testes. valeu

Answer (score 4):

Pode utilizar o parâmetro `ignore.case` da função `grep`conforme consta na [documentação](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/grep).

Para seu caso:

```
txt <- c("1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"2º ano", "2º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "4º ano", 
"4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", 
"1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"2º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", 
"4º ano", "4º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "1º ano", 
"1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", 
"4º ano", "5 º ano", "5 º ano", "5 º ano", "5 º ano", "1º ano", 
"1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "1º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", "2º ano", 
"2º ano", "2º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", "3º ano", 
"4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "4º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", 
"5º ano", "5º ano", "5º ano", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"1º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"2º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"3º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"4º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", 
"5º ANO - MATUTINO/VESPERTINO", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 1º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 2º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 3º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 4º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", 
"Anos iniciais 5º ano / Parcial", "1º ANO", "1º ANO", "1º ANO", 
"1º ANO", "1º ANO", "1º ANO", "2º ANO", "2º ANO", "2º ANO", "2º ANO", 
"2º ANO", "2º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", "3º ANO", 
"3º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", "4º ANO", 
"5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "5º ANO", "1 º ano", 
"1 º ano", "1 º ano", "1 º ano", "1 º ano", "1 º ano", "2ºano", 
"2ºano", "2ºano", "2ºano", "2ºano", "2ºano", "3ºano", "3ºano", 
"3ºano", "3ºano", "3ºano", "3ºano", "4ºano", "4ºano", "4ºano", 
"4ºano", "4ºano", "4ºano", "5ºano")

grep("1º ano", txt, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

[Um exemplo funcional no **Rextester**.](http://rextester.com/JKXNR67371)

Comment: `ignore.case` resolve os casos de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas e já é um adianto, só que pros casos de `1 º ano` e `1ºano` talvez tenha alguma saída

Comment: o caractere especial `?` define o caractere que vem antes dele como opcional. Deste modo, ficaria `1 ?º ?ano`, encontrando os casos quando os espaços estão presentes ou não.